# React Storybook is not initializing: npx sb init is throwing node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1078 error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, components, storybook

I was creating a React Component Library, and when i tried initiallizing storybook i get this node error that relates to some deprecated package or my node version (Node.js v18.14.2 LTS).

I tried initiallizing storybook with `npx sb init` and got these

````
Need to install the following packages:
  sb@6.5.16
Ok to proceed? (y)
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1078
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'is-arrayish'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\d28cfb4b54958d89\node_modules\error-ex\index.js
- C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\d28cfb4b54958d89\node_modules\parse-json\index.js
- C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\d28cfb4b54958d89\node_modules\read-pkg\index.js
- C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\d28cfb4b54958d89\node_modules\read-pkg-up\index.js
- C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\d28cfb4b54958d89\node_modules\@storybook\cli\dist\cjs\generate.js
- C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\d28cfb4b54958d89\node_modules\@storybook\cli\bin\index.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)      
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\d28cfb4b54958d89\node_modules\error-ex\index.js:4:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)       
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\d28cfb4b54958d89\\node_modules\\error-ex\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\d28cfb4b54958d89\\node_modules\\parse-json\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\d28cfb4b54958d89\\node_modules\\read-pkg\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\d28cfb4b54958d89\\node_modules\\read-pkg-up\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\d28cfb4b54958d89\\node_modules\\@storybook\\cli\\dist\\cjs\\generate.js',
    'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\d28cfb4b54958d89\\node_modules\\@storybook\\cli\\bin\\index.js'
  ]
}

Node.js v18.14.2```
````

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by using `npx storybook init` instead of `npx sb init`.

Also, note that storybook still uses webpack4 (as at the time of this answer) by default which might cause loads of issues.
So to use webpack5 run `npx storybook init --builder webpack5`

If you are already using the webpack4 builder, to upgrade:

- Delete `storybook` and `stories` folder.
- Remove anything related to storybook from `package.json`
- Delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`
- run `npm install`
- run `npx storybook init --builder webpack5`

Another thing to know, that might save a lot of folks time is that storybook uses `react-dom` so if you run into any such error, just install it with

`npm i -D react-dom`.

`-D` is used here because in my case i wanted it as a dev dependency.

Adios.